# where is my window title dude?

Tags: colors, window, titanium, appcelerator, title

everyone, my question is very simple:
I'm using Android emulator.
I try to create a simple empty window with title (so simple))
But..... Why doesn't this code works properly:

```
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('#1E563F');

var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'HOY',
    exitOnClose: true
});

win1.open();
```

I see on my emulator empty window with title === 'name of my project' but != 'HOY', why is that?
And if i add string
        navBarHidden: true
I have empty, BLACK window... WTF... I expected at least window with color == #1E563F...

Comment: Okey, i've solved this problem...

Comment: You need to create window with     navBarHidden: false

Comment: Please post your answer and accept that.. so that question could be marked as solved...

Comment: AplphaMale i will accept my answer at the day after tomorrow. Because system doesn't allows me to do this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create window as:

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'HOY',
    exitOnClose: true,
    navBarHidden: false,
    backgroundColor: '#1E563F'   
});
```